# Jquery hover (mouseover) works but hover (mouseRemove) function does not load

Tags: jquery, hover, jquery-animate, jquery-hover

Hi there this is my first legitimate question for stackoverflow, forgive me if I mess up on some social policies. I'm working on Jquery, and I am using these plugins.

```
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.color-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
```

To make this section of code work:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var timeout;
    $('.twitter').hover(

    function () {
        timeout = setTimeout(

        function () {
            $('body').animate({
                "background-color": "#dd4b39"
            }, 400);
        },

        function () {
            $('body').animate({
                "background-color": "#000000"
            }, 400);
            clearTimeout(timeout);
        });
    });
});
```

[Here's a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/josephmcasey/LBBja/)

The code will activate the hover effect and change the div to a soft red, but it won't change the div to a solid black when you move your mouse off the div. Most examples of this online suggest an extremely similar approach, so I'm curious as to where I fouled this up.

**EDIT 8/27/13 18:28 EST**

I guess the history would be necessary, my original code was a very simple function, but it had the problem of buildings of a queue of animate functions before moving onto the next animate.

[Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/josephmcasey/PYNF7/) (move your mouse between the two divs quickly)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.twitter').hover(
        function() {$('body').animate({"background-color":"#00aced"}, 400);},
        function() {$('body').animate({"background-color":"#232323"}, 400);}
    );
    $('.facebook').hover(
        function() {$('body').animate({"background-color":"#3b5998"}, 400);},
        function() {$('body').animate({"background-color":"#232323"}, 400);}
    );
});
```

I thought I had correctly constructed a timeout function that would stop the animation of the previous hover function if you initiated a new hover function, preventing the building up animations.

Comment: Your code is really weird, what are you trying to do with the setTimeout? And why your mouseout is not working? Is because you haven't given `hover` the mouseout function.

Comment: When you provide a fiddle make sure to include the needed libraries, here's an updated fiddle with the jQuery and jQuery UI libraries http://jsfiddle.net/LBBja/2/ also I second the previous comment, why do you need the tiemout?

Comment: Thanks @koala_dev, I've never asked for help, so the whole JSFiddle is new to me. Noted for the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To stop the animation queue from building up what you need to do is call [`stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) before the call to `animate()`:

```
$('.twitter').hover(
    function() {$('body').stop().animate({"background-color":"#00aced"}, 400);},
    function() {$('body').stop().animate({"background-color":"#232323"}, 400);}
);
```

**[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PYNF7/1/)**

Comment: :( I'll spend so long on a silly problems; and, gosh, it is always so simple. Thanks for answering @koala_dev.

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what you are trying to do there with the `setTimeout` but is in the wrong position. `hover` accepts two functions, one `mouseover` and one `mouseout`. So it should be something on the line of :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.twitter').hover(
        function () {
            $('body').animate({
                "background-color": "#dd4b39"
            }, 400);
        },

        function () {
            $('body').animate({
                "background-color": "#000000"
            }, 400);
        }
    );
});
```

If what you wanted to do with `setTimeout` was create a delay, you can add `delay` before the `animate` function: `$('body').delay(1000).animate(....`

For more info on `hover`: http://api.jquery.com/hover/

Comment: Thanks putvande for establishing that I incorrectly formatted the original one (I was afraid that was the problem), this is the original code I had; and I was hoping to fix the build up of functions.

Comment: Does this fix your problem? If so, could you be so kind to accept it.

Comment: It didn't fix my problem. The delay made the buildup problem worse. My apologies for not getting to that sooner.